# Debugging solution, having #if for every output of some action

Tags: c++, debugging

Is there better solution for debugging than this?

```
// for every part of code where i wanna know the output of some action

#if defined DEBUG_LEVEL
    std::cout << output << std::endl;
#endif
```

Comment: Are you looking for a better/more compact way for the debug code to get taken out at compile time, or are you looking for just a better way in general?

Answer (score 2):

```
#if defined DEBUG_LEVEL
    #define OutputDebugString(x) std::cout << (x) << std::endl
#else
    #define OutputDebugString(x)
#endif
```

And then just use `OutputDebugString(x);` wherever; it'll be removed if you compile without `DEBUG_LEVEL`.

Comment: If you don't put `x` in brackets you will be able to do `OutputDebugString(a << b << c)` type things. Of course then you will need to put brackets in when calling the macro when needed `OutputDebugString((a + b) << " items")`.